# Problema com ordenação de vetor

Tags: c, loop

Boa tarde, estou tendo um problema com um exercício de ordenação de vetores, já revisei o código, ele compila, mas não estou achando o erro para a ordem não ficar de forma crescente, variando em certos trechos. Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h> //Declaracao de bibliteca para entradas e saidas de valores

int main (void) //Declaracao do programa principal
{
    int i, j, troca, vetorA[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o valor do elemento:");
        scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; j<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j<10; j++)
        {   
            if(vetorA[i]>vetorA[j])
            {
                troca=vetorA[i];
                vetorA[i] = vetorA[j];
                vetorA[j] = troca;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nvetor ordenado \n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d - ", vetorA[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

em vez de

```
for(i=0; j<10; i++)
```

pqrece-me que querias dizer

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que era um erro de digitação apenas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int troca, vetorA[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Digite o valor do elemento:");
        scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // <=========== Aqui tinha um j < 10 que obviamente causa confusão
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {  
            if (vetorA[i] > vetorA[j]) {
                troca = vetorA[i];
                vetorA[i] = vetorA[j];
                vetorA[j] = troca;
             }
        }
    }
    printf("\nvetor ordenado\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d - ", vetorA[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/PdNIJA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jmtunxrn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Sortingx.c).